# platform specific code in cordova 4.1.2

Tags: cordova

The "merges" folder that used to be created by default in earlier cordova versions when creating a cordova project and adding platforms

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

is no longer available in cordova 4.1.2

The folder is not created at all anymore. Even if I manually create it, the cordova cli doesn't pickup the resources from it anymore.

I cannot use the older cordova version because I need to support windows 8.1 which is available only in the latest so, is there a way i can still manage platform specific code in cordova 4.1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok it worked .. i was putting the files inside merges/windows/www/js/customFile.js

which should have been merges/windows/js/customFile.js